# repopulate php dynamic checkboxes from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am using a loop to create dynamic checkboxes as described [here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm)

Everything works as expected and I have successfully created a table with 2 columns: userid and preferences.
Each checkbox has a unique preference value associated and If it is checked, then php stores it in a mysql database.

Now i need to repopulate the checkboxes if the user comes back on the page another day.

My idea (maybe not good enough..)

`SELECT preference FROM Preference table WHERE UserId=CurrentUserId`

and I can call the `query result ---> $result[]`

Now I got all the preferences of a certain user in a variable and I can make a loop with a IF condition when creating the dynamic checkboxes:

IF `$result` equals the current checkbox id then write `checked`

but I am not fully sure how to make it work and if it would work..any ideas?

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty solution. It's obviously not the best, but it gets the job done. $form = 'Your HTML content';
$form = str_replace("<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{$result}\" />", "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{$result}\" checked />", $form);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly as you said.

1. Get the preferences from database for the current online user (`$clientId`).

   ```
   $query = "SELECT preference FROM Preference WHERE userId = $clientId";
   $res = sql_query($query, $connection);
   while($userPreference = mysql_fetch_array($res))
     $userPreferences[$userPreference] = true;
   ```

   I will assume they have a unique identifier called `preference`.
2. Iterate over all the preferences, checking against the selected `$userPreferences` from database.

   ```
   foreach($preferences as $preference) {
     $checked = $userPreferences[$preference] ? 'checked' : '';
     echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$preference}' $checked />";
   }
   ```

Something like this should be enough to recreate the layout and choose user preferences.

Comment: I tried to implement your code but I am a beginner and I didn't succeed.. I pasted my full code here: maybe you can understand better http://codepad.org/qluIjByA